# win32 Semaphores

Tags: multithreading, winapi, semaphore

I am trying to create a simple semaphore that will allow  only 1 thread to increment a count variable but what I am currently doing does not seem to work. Is there something wrong with my syntax or am I completely on the wrong track? (I named the semaphore mutex, because it can only have a value of 0 or 1)

```
WaitForSingleObject(mutex, 0);
count = count + 1;
ReleaseSemaphore(mutex, 1, NULL);
```

Comment: Do check return values for error conditions, especially in multi-threaded code which effectively must be correct by construction since you can't effectively demonstrate it to be correct by testing. For the specific case of an atomic increment of a value, consider using [InterlockedIncrement()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or one of its close relatives.

Comment: Isn't a critical section better for this scenario, or maybe the Interlocked* set of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032.aspx), with emphasis added:

> ```
> DWORD WINAPI WaitForSingleObject(
>     __in  HANDLE hHandle,
>     __in  DWORD dwMilliseconds
> );
> ```
>
> *dwMilliseconds* [in]
>   The time-out interval, in milliseconds. If a nonzero value is specified, the function waits until the object is signaled or the interval elapses. **If *dwMilliseconds* is zero, the function does not enter a wait state if the object is not signaled; it always returns immediately. If *dwMilliseconds* is `INFINITE`, the function will return only when the object is signaled.**

Answer (score 0):

Try `INFINITE` rather than zero as your second argument to `WaitForSingleObject`.

Comment: same problem with infinite. What I am trying to do is print out count in order from 0 to 10 using multiple threads. So I have a thread print the value and then use a semaphore for mutual exclusion on the increment so two threads cannot increment the value at the same time.